# MassTransit - Azure Functions / Service Bus - Consume not being used to consume message

Tags: masstransit

I have used the sample found at 
https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/tree/develop/src/Samples/Sample.AzureFunctions.ServiceBus. The function correctly executes when a message hits the Queue, however the consume code registered by the following never gets executed...

`cfg.Consumer(() => new SubmitOrderConsumer());`

the consume class

```
public class SubmitOrderConsumer :
        IConsumer<SubmitOrder>
    {
        public Task Consume(ConsumeContext<SubmitOrder> context)
        {
            LogContext.Debug?.Log("Processing Order: {OrderNumber}", context.Message.OrderNumber);

            context.Publish<OrderReceived>(new
            {
                context.Message.OrderNumber,
                Timestamp = DateTime.UtcNow
            });

            return context.RespondAsync<OrderAccepted>(new {context.Message.OrderNumber});
        }
    }
```

Is there anything else I could be missing, is this supported in .net Core 3?

Thanks

Comment: Does the type name (including namespace) of the message written to the service bus queue match the type being consumed by the consumer? Are all the proper envelope headers added to the message?

Comment: Thanks Chris, it was the namespace. I got this correct when I was consuming via a service, but forgot about it in the function consumer. Thanks again.